# How to make text faint and disabled in an entry or input field in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, input, text, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make the text kind of disabled in the background. But the user also cannot write text when I make it disabled

The question was already asked by someone,
But those answers were not clear to me and were not satisfying.
So I decided to post this question.

I want the text to be similar to the input fields on the login pages of most websites, where some text like 'Username' or 'Password' is already written in the input fields.

So the text should be a little bit faint, and when the users starts typing the text should disappear. So The user should not be able to copy it and doesn't need to remove it before typing.

This is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

my_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
my_entry.pack()
my_entry.insert(0, "Enter Your Name")
my_entry.configure(state=DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```

The user also cannot write text in the input field.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please improve your wording, so that the users are willing to help. Deciphering your question(s) does not increase the willingness of to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

my_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
my_entry.pack()
my_entry.insert(0, "Enter Your Name")
my_entry.configure(state=DISABLED)

def on_click(event):
    my_entry.configure(state=NORMAL)
    my_entry.delete(0, END)

    # make the callback only work once
    my_entry.unbind('<Button-1>', on_click_id)

on_click_id = my_entry.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

As a class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class DefaultEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, default_text='', **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.insert(0, default_text)
        self.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.on_click_id = self.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, _):
        self.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.delete(0, tk.END)

        # unregister myself
        self.unbind('<Button-1>', self.on_click_id)

root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = DefaultEntry(root, width=50, default_text='Enter your Name')
my_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad the global `on_click_id` is a bit ugly, consider subclassing `Entry`. (I also prefer to import `tkinter as tk` in order to not override any already existing names without noticing.)

Comment: I don't understand Sir, What do you mean by 'subclassing' Entry.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad I mean taking the `Entry` widget and extending it with the logic you need. I edited that extended class into my answer. You can now use `DefaultEntry` anywhere you need an entry with that behavior.

Comment: your code won't work if the entry gets focus because the user used the tab key.

Comment: @BryanOakley that's correct, I'm assuming OP will figure out how to bind all the events they like, using my code as their starting point.